# How to group by time and do (and only keep) the mean of the 3 last elements in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have this Python's DataFrame :

```
temperature time
10.196833   01-03-2019 00:00:00
11.084986   01-03-2019 00:00:00
10.196833   01-03-2019 00:00:00
10.18458    01-03-2019 00:00:00
10.397547   01-03-2019 00:00:00
10.397547   01-03-2019 00:00:00
9.675623    01-03-2019 01:00:00
10.382349   01-03-2019 01:00:00
9.675623    01-03-2019 01:00:00
9.609171    01-03-2019 01:00:00
9.901361    01-03-2019 01:00:00
9.901361    01-03-2019 01:00:00
8.960459    01-03-2019 02:00:00
10.513941   01-03-2019 02:00:00
8.960459    01-03-2019 02:00:00
10.213129   01-03-2019 02:00:00
9.446863    01-03-2019 02:00:00
9.446863    01-03-2019 02:00:00
```

there is one day but 3 hours ( 00:00 to 02:00)
I would like to only conserve the 3 last lines for each hour and do on it a GroupBy mean to only have the mean of the 3 last elements of each hour :

```
temperature time
10.326558       01-03-2019 00:00:00
9.8039643       01-03-2019 01:00:00
9.702285        01-03-2019 02:00:00
```

I tried :

```
dataframe = df.groupby(time).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[-3]]).mean
```

But I just got an error

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: "IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds"

Comment: `dataframe = df.groupby(time).temprature.mean()`. Try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.
This line provides the required output:

```
ddf = df.groupby('time').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[-3:].mean())
```

With `ddf` resulting in:

```
                     temperature
time                            
2019-01-03 00:00:00    10.326558
2019-01-03 01:00:00     9.803964
2019-01-03 02:00:00     9.702285
```

To use the last 3 rows, you need to slice, you forgot the `:`. And there is a pair of extra brackets which are usually not required by `iloc`.